# Kafka Streams: Is it possible to have "compact,delete" policy on state stores?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka Streams state stores are "compact" by default. Is it possible to set "compact,delete" with a retention policy in a state store?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to configure topics with retention and compaction and Kafka Streams uses this setting for windowed `KTable`s.

If you really want to set this, you can update the corresponding changelog topic config manually after it is created.

However, setting topic retention time for changelog topics deletes the data only from the topic. Data is **not deleted** in the local state store. State stores don't offer TTL and RocksDBs TTL setting cannot be enabled (for technical reasons that we hope to resolve eventually).

If you want to delete data cleanly, you should use tombstone messages that will delete the data from the store as well as the changelog topic (instead of using retention time).

Comment: So, you can just send tombstone messages to the statestore changelog topic, and then the "live" statestore will learn about them and apply them to the in-mem & RocksDB representation?

Comment: No. You should never write to the changelog topic! This would mess up your state. If you read a topic directly as a table (`builder.table(...)`) you write the tombstone into the input topic. If you table is a result of an aggregation, your aggregator needs to return `null` as aggregation result; this, will delete the key from the store and write a tombstone to the changelog.

Comment: Thinking in PAPI, store.delete(Key) for KVStore and store.remove(WindowedKey) will handle all of it, then?

Comment: In the case of a window store, I guess to delete all entries you would need to fetch(key) and loop over the iterator removing each WindowedKey entry individually, right?

Comment: That is possible. Note, that a window store applies a retention time. This might be already provide what you need without deleting old windows via custom code.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax is there any kafka/kafka streams documentation described that log.retention.* does not affect local store? It is a bit confusing. If I have log.retention configuration set up for all topics in `server.properties` does it mean all changelog topics will be out of sync with local state stores because local ones will have old data?

Comment: Note that there is "broker configs" and "topic config" -- when Kafka Streams creates changelog topic, it will set explicit topic config and not use broker default configs. To double check, you can "describe topics" to inspect their configuration via command line tool `bin/kafka-topics.sh`. -- I actually believe, that the docs are little sparse here -- Btw: Kafka is an open source project and PR that improve the docs are very welcome!!!

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for the great answer (as always), is there now an idiomatic way to propagate the source topic deletions (given that it is a compact,delete topic) to the local state store? Or should we use a windowed state store as a work around?

Comment: Nothing changes so far -- you can use a windowed-store, but not directly via `builder.table()`. You would need to do read the topic as `KStream` and do a windowed-aggregation to get a windowed-KTable.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Would the following still corrupt the state store ? `(1)` shutdown the streams application `(2)` rm -rf <state_dir> `(3)` clear messages from the changelog topic

Comment: Yes. The changelog topic is the source of truth, and if you delete it you basically clear all your accumulated state. Not sure why you are asking?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I wanted to check if there's a way to reset the state store and changelog without corrupting the state. The reason is am seeing an extremely high usage of disk space by sst/LOG files , even though the streams application did remove all records.

Comment: It seems we are using the term "corrupted" differently... To me "corrupted" means that you lose data -- of course, if you want to clean all your state, you can delete the local state directory and clear the changelog and restart the app -- it will start up with empty state for this case (ie, "corrupted state" in the way I use the term).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default RocksDBStore there is an option to set up CompactionStyle to FIFO:

> FIFO compaction style is the simplest compaction strategy. It is suited for keeping event log data with very low overhead (query log for example). It periodically deletes the old data, so it's basically a TTL compaction style.

and then use the TTL:

> A new option, compaction_options_fifo.ttl, has been introduced for this to delete SST files for which the TTL has expired. This feature enables users to drop files based on time rather than always based on size, say, drop all SST files older than a week or a month.

[RocksDB FIFO doc](http://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/FIFO-compaction-style)

To actually set the FIFO you have to implement RocksDBConfigSetter and set it as configuration property: rocksdb.config.setter